# Google API PHP, Service Account Impersonation issues

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I've tried every combination of things to try and gain some progress on this issue but I can't get anywhere. I'm trying to use a service account to access a calendar of a user on the domain. The service account is setup, appears to be working fine. As far as I can tell the Domain-wide Delegation is  enabled according to https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount?hl=en_US#delegatingauthority. In my code below, Everything works fine until I set the impersonation account and I get the error in the title. I've seen various different posts about authenticating the impersonator user etc. but that doesn't seem to align with what google says. I'm stuck.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setSubject('email@domain.com');
$client->setAuthConfig($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/private.json');
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']);
```

This will cause any type of api request to fail with the error:

```
Message: {
 "error": "unauthorized_client",
 "error_description": "Unauthorized client or scope in request."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how are you?

For its code shown miss you release the scopo that your application will use, if you want to use Google Calendar, you must use this:

$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly');

More information on scopes: 
[OAuth 2.0 Scopes for Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#calendarv3)

:)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did have that set but didn't include in original question, but updated.

Comment: You added the service key created in the Google Developer Console there in the Admin Console?

The following tutorial: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts#delegatingauthority